# Xcode 12.0 debug view doesn`t show variables

Tags: xcode, debugging

I have a problem which I can't fix. For some reason xcode stoped show me variables in debug mode with breakpoint.

Schema set in debug
Optimization mode set in none

Who can help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkBOf.png

Comment: Where is the breakpoint?

Comment: No matter where. On any part of code where I want to put breakpoint app stop but debug view doesn`t show me variables of class.

Comment: It does sound like a bug. Try nudging it. :) Change All to the first option instead. Add some Filter text and then remove it again. See if any of that makes the variables come back to life.

Comment: I found a reason. Latest Firebase release has broke xcode debuger and also sometime crash the app.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger may not show the value of your variables for any of the following reasons:

The Optimization level is not set to None for the Debug configuration.
Be sure to set it to None for Swift apps as shown in Figure 1 and for Swift apps as shown in Figure 2.

The Build Configuration pop-up menu is set to Release in the scheme editor's Run action settings pane.
In Xcode, open the scheme editor by choosing Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme…, select the Run action for your app in the scheme actions pane, then set Build Configuration to Debug as seen in Figure 3.

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: To view all variables in the debugger, the current Optimization Level Debug setting is `-Onone`